# Need to put an average wait time for my shortest job first in C

Tags: c, job-scheduling

Everything's working, I just need help with the average waiting time and total waiting time.

```
#include<cstdio>

typedef struct nonpresjf{
    int at,bt,tat,wt;
}nonpresjf;

nonpresjf p[20],p1[20];

int main(void){
    int i,limit,nextval,m,min,n;
    p[0].wt=p[0].tat=0;

    printf("\nEnter the no of process: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        printf("Enter the arrival time: ");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].at);
    }
    limit=p[1].at;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        printf("Enter the burst time: ");
        scanf("%d",&p[i].bt);
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        limit+=p[i].bt;
    }

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
p1[i]=p[i];


printf("\n\nGantt chart is as follows: ");
printf("%d",p[1].at);
nextval=p[1].at;
m=1;

    do{
        min = 9999;
        for(i=1;p[i].at<=nextval && i<=n ;i++)
            if(p[i].bt<min && p[i].bt>0){
                m=i;
                min=p[i].bt;
            }

        nextval+=p[m].bt;
        p[m].bt=0;

        printf("->P%d->%d",m,nextval);

        if(p[m].bt==0){
            p[m].tat=nextval-p[m].at;
            p[m].wt=p[m].tat-p1[m].bt;
            p[0].tat+=p[m].tat;
            p[0].wt+=p[m].wt;
            //SHOWS TABLE
        }
    }while(nextval<limit);

    p[0].tat=p[0].tat/n;
    p[0].wt=p[0].wt/n;

    printf("\n\n-------------------TABLE----------------------------------\n");

    printf("\nProcess\tAT\tBT\tTAT\tWT\n");

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    printf("\nP%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",i,p[i].at,p1[i].bt,p[i].tat,p[i].wt);
    printf("\n\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I just need help in adding the average waiting time.

Comment: Why are you repeating yourself ?

Comment: I edited your post because there was no way to understand what you exactly tried to do.

Comment: Please clarify. What is the problem ? What is your actual an output ? What output do you expect ?

Comment: You have computed the wt for each process, then sum up an divide by n? What am I missing? It is too difficult to see farther than this, the code is long and very difficult to read.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I just need it to compute the Average waiting time.